# Creating new list out of two lists in c#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Is it be possible to write it more cleaner way using linq.

```
//retrieved from db
List<User> existingList = new List<User>()
{
new User() {
Id = 1,
Name = "test1",
City = "City1"
},
new User() {
Id = 2,
Name = "test2",
City = "City"
}
};

//modified by ui
List<User> modifiedlist = new List<User>()
{
new User() {
Id = 1,
Name = "test1",
City = "City1"
},
new User() {
Id = 3,
Name = "test3",
City = "City3"
}
};
```

**in db: (Going By modified list) I need to add user 3 and remove user 2 and don't bother about 1.

**for deleting user2, I am looping through existing list and if not present in modified list, then remove 2.  **for adding user3, i am looping through modified list and if not present in existing list, add 3

Comment: Code example of what you're currently doing, please?

Comment: We need more information to answer this for you.  Where does the 4 come from?  Is it another list?  Why did 4 get added and why didn't 1 get removed with 2 and 3?

Comment: There's still not enough information.  Providing a code example as of what you're actually doing will help clarify, as dodexahedron said.  Or provide more context, as my comment above asks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like exactly what you need.
[How to: Find the Set Difference Between Two Lists (LINQ):](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397894.aspx)

```
        List<int> existingList = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
        List<int> modifiedList = new List<int>() { 1, 3 };

        var usersToDelete = existingList.Except(modifiedList).ToList(); //contains '2'
        var usersToAdd = modifiedList.Except(existingList).ToList(); //contains '3'
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the subject... He wishes to add and remove items efficiently, while all you do is finding differences and no alerting to the list.

Answer (score -1):

If you know that it is 1,2,3 and you know you want it 1,4 - then you can just RemoveAt(2) to remove 3, and then set [1] to 4 to change 2 into a 4. RemoveAt is faster than Remove, because it goes by index.

```
var list = new List<int> {1,2,3};

list.RemoveAt(2);
list[1] = 4;
```

But of course if you don't know if the numbers you wish to remove exist or not, and where they exist, you obviously need to search for them...

Now, lets say you know that the list is sorted, and is huge.
Let us consider the case where the list has 10,000 elements {0,2,5,6,8,...} random sorted numbers, and you wish to remove all numbers that are in list `toRemove`, which is also sorted {3,5,6,7,...}

THEN you can actually iterate the list once except for `toRemove.Count` times, like so:

```
int j = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count && j < toRemove.Count; i++)
{
    if (list[i] == toRemove[j])
    {
        list.RemoveAt(i);
        j++;
        i--;
    }
}
```

And if the list might contain duplicate numbers {1, 4, 4, 5, 7,...} and you want to remove 4 in a way that not a single 4 will exist, then you need to do:

```
int j = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count && j < toRemove.Count; i++)
{
    var currRemove = toRemove[j];

    while (list[i] == currRemove)
    {
        list.RemoveAt(i);
        i--;
    }

    j++;
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want it to be more clean and less efficient, you can do:

```
list = list.Except(toRemove).Union(toAdd).ToList();
```

and if you don't want to add items that already exist:

```
var tmp = list.Except(toRemove);
list = list.Union(toAdd.Except(tmp)).ToList();
```

But I must say this would be terribly slow and you might want to reconsider using a list, and perhaps using a HashTable or a **Dictionary**.

Comment: This will modify the original array in ways I don't think the OP intended.  And it's also a very specific solution to what seems to be a general question.

Comment: @dodexahedron Yes, and I did talk about the general case as well, saying that you can't remove items that you don't know their index without iterating over the list.

Comment: I think we can all agree we need a better clarification of the question, then. :)

Comment: I am sorry, it is difficult to compose. I tried to modify it, please let me know if I need to be still clear. I cannot use index operations like RemoveAt.

Comment: @Sundeep What we need to know is how you decided that you want to remove and what you want to add - where do those things come from in your code.

Comment: @Nathan, As commented, existing list comes from db and modifiedlist is from ui changes...

Comment: I'd like to point out that your answer completely ignores the very first line of the OP's question,  which is this: "Is it be possible to write it more _cleaner_ way using **Linq**."   Please see my answer below.

Comment: @Kal_Torak Fair point, but he seemed more concerned about not having to loop through the lists multiple times. Also, emphasizing a different word: "Is it be possible to write *it* more cleaner way using Linq." to point out that you didn't to *it*, but a *different* thing.

Comment: Thanks Nathan and Torak, both were helpful. Since performance is not a big criteria, I would use LINQ. Thanks again!